# Jupyterhub terminal path variable

Tags: ipython, jupyter, jupyter-notebook, jupyterhub, jupyter-console

When I open a terminal on JupyterHub and try to run commands that I've placed in the machine's path, it says "command not found."

The default PATH variable on Jupyterhub terminal seems to be `/sbin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin` and I'm wondering why it doesn't use the PATH as defined on the machine. Is there a way to get it to inherit this PATH, or to run some command like `source /etc/environment` whenever a terminal is generated?

Answer (score 2):

Turns out that when you edit `/etc/bash.bashrc` on the machine to include the PATH variable, it then persists in the Jupyterhub terminal